# Jquery UI Tabs - slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I switch tabs by sliding them horizontally? Currently I have:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } });
```

I'd like [an effect similar to this](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/slidingpanels/SlidingPanelsSample.html#HorizontalSliding).

Thanks!

Comment: On this page there is an example on animation for UI tabs:
http://www.eduteka.org/ajax/tabs3/

Answer (score 1):

Go to sprinkle.js and change highlighted to width:

$('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ fx: { **height**: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } });